# Generating number after a set of interval

Tags: javascript, loops, hitcounter

I am trying to display random number like every after 20 seconds. The code I have below only display when the browser is refresh. What I would like to happen is the number change without refreshing the browser on an infinite loop ranging from 1 - 100

```
function visitorounter(){
        var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
        document.write("<strong>"+randomnumber+"</strong>");
}

visitorounter()
```

Comment: Repeating the function itself can be done with `setInterval(visitorounter,20000);` (or `setTimeout(visitorounter, 20000);` at the end of your function), but it seems you want to overwrite the existing value. Is how to overwrite an existing element part of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your own approach is likely to be the use of `document.write` after the document has – presumably – finished loading; which either causes the page to be reloaded to show, or entirely over-written by, the supplied string of HTML.

I'd suggest the following approach (as one of many alternatives):

```
// using a named function to generate the random numbers:
function randomNumber () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}
function visitorounter() {

    // retrieving the element in which the random number
    // should be shown:
    var elem = document.getElementById('randomNumber');

    // updating that element's text-content to show the
    // first random number immediately:
    elem.textContent = randomNumber();

    // setting the interval (20000ms) after which the
    // the supplied anonymous function should be run:
    window.setInterval(function () {

        // updating the text of the element:
        elem.textContent = randomNumber();
    }, 20000);
}

visitorounter();
```

```js
function randomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}

function visitorounter() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('randomNumber');
  elem.textContent = randomNumber();
  window.setInterval(function() {
    elem.textContent = randomNumber();
  }, 20000);
}

visitorounter();
```

```html
<p id="randomNumber"></p>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/z1r0xroo/) for experimentation and development.

References:

- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).
- [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).
- [`Window.setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
setInterval(function counter() {
  var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    document.write("<strong>"+randomnumber+"</strong>");
}, 20000);
```

Or something like this:

```
(function counter(cb) {
  setTimeout(function() { 
    cb(); 
    return counter(cb); 
  }, 20000);
})(function() {
  var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    document.write("<strong>"+randomnumber+"</strong>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `setInterval()` and setting 20000 ms (milliseconds)

```
setInterval(function() {
    visitorounter();
}, 20000);
```

However, it is preferred to use a `setTimeout` loop with recursion.

```
function myTimeout() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        visitorounter();
        myTimeout(); // recursive function call
    }, 20000);
}
myTimeout();
```

The second version performs a lot better.

---

If you want the number to change, don't use `document.write()`, instead create an element with an id and use that.

```
<div id="counter"></div>
```

And replace `document.write` with this:

```
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = randomnumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will generate Random number with a specific counter range OR infinite loop with specific Random range:

```
// fixed to 1
var i = 1;
// 0 infinite loop OR 1 and higher for specific count range
var max_count = 0;
// delay in second
var delay = 20;
var randomRange = 100;

function myCounter() {
    // first random number
    if (i == 1) {
        visitorounter();
        i++;
        myCounter();
    } else {
        // delayed random numbers
        setTimeout(function () {
            visitorounter();
            i++;
            if (i <= max_count) {
                myCounter();
            }
            if (max_count == 0) {
                myCounter();
            }
        }, (delay * 1000))
    }
}

myCounter();

function visitorounter() {
    document.getElementById('randomNumber').innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomRange);
}
```

And add following line to your html

```
<div id="randomNumber"></div>
```

Inspiration http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_setinterval2